# How to execute function right after every single keypress

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my unit converter. I want it to execute `convert()` function right after every single key press. `keyup` and `keydown` work only after I press return or click mouse somewhere else. I want it to work simultaneously, like GTranslator.

**JS**

```
var text;
var number;
var index;
var index2;

const test = document.getElementById("userInputNumber");
test.addEventHandler("keypress", convert);


function convert() {
    text = document.getElementById("userInputNumber").value;
    number = parseFloat(text);
    determineUnit();
    convertUnit();
    document.getElementById("result").value = number;
}

function determineUnit() {
    index = document.getElementById("mySelect1").selectedIndex;
    if (index === 0) {
    number = number * 1000;
    } else if (index === 1) {
        number = number * 1;
    } else if (index === 2) {
        number = number * 0.01;
    } else {
        number = number * 0.001;
    }
}

function convertUnit() {
    index2 = document.getElementById("mySelect2").selectedIndex;
    if (index2 === 0) {
    number = number * 0.001;
    } else if (index2 === 1) {
        number = number * 1;
    } else if (index2 === 2) {
        number = number * 100;
    } else {
        number = number * 1000;
    }
}

    document.getElementById("Reset").reset();
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="converter" onsubmit="return false"> 

        <input type="text" id="userInputNumber">

        <select id="mySelect1">
            <option value="kilometers">Kilometers</option>
            <option value="meters" selected>Meters</option>
            <option value="centimeters">Centimeters</option>
            <option value="millimeters">Millimeters</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="result" disabled>

        <select id="mySelect2">
            <option value="kilometers">Kilometers</option>
            <option value="meters">Meters</option>
            <option value="centimeters">Centimeters</option>
            <option value="millimeters">Millimeters</option>
        </select>

      <button class="convertButton" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>

      <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </form>
```

Comment: `test.addEventListener("keyup", convert())` is wrong. You are executing the function and returning what it returns to the keyup event,....

Comment: @epascarello it works thought, but only after mouse click or return press. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: You should remove the "onchange" handler from the `<input>`; that's why it's working the way it does. The `.addEventHandler()` call should pass just `convert`, not `convert()`.

Comment: Note that "keyup" will fire *before* the `<input>` value is affected by the keyboard interaction. You might find that "keypress" is closer to what you want.

Comment: @Pointy right, changed it - still doesn't work the way I want it.

Comment: @Pointy I used `keypress` and `keydown` as well. No difference.

Comment: Well there's not really enough code to see what's going on; in particular, those two other functions aren't posted. It would help if you'd update this question with the most recent attempts at making it work. And if you tried "keypress" without fixing the `addEventHandler()` call then no, that would not help.

Comment: @Pointy updated code. `addEventHandler()` doesn't work at all. Now it converts only after pressing submit button.

Comment: Well if your code is in a `<script>` block *before* the document body, then you're also probably seeing errors in the console. The could should either be in a "load" or "ready" handler or (simpler) moved to just before the `</body>` closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best solution I found is to use `onkeydown="convert()"` in HTML, and this work quite well, except first number – when I type only one number output gives me NaN. When I press return it converts, when I continue typing more numbers it works as magic. I don't understand why program doesn't convert first string to number.

Comment: "keydown" is fired before the "value" attribute of the `<input>` is changed.

Comment: @Pointy I changed it to `keyup` and it works almost perfect. Except when you delete all digits output returns NaN. I assume that there is a way to just block NaN . But I'm wondering isn't there another smart way to do simultaneous conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution i can suggest is to use KeyPress

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', convert);

function convert(e) {
  //Your Code Here
}
```

If u want to check what key the user pressed, u can use this`` ${e.code}`;`  inside the convert function .